# Audio Enter Phaser?

Tags: javascript, audio, phaser-framework

I'm designing a game where the player will be given 4 sounds and they have to guess what the sounds have in common. It works exactly as "4 pictures 1 word" game but instead of pictures, the player has to guess the sounds.

The user has to press key 1,2,3 and 4 to hear the sounds. Once the player has heard the sounds, the player has to guess what the sounds have in common. How do I code the part where after the player has heard the 4 sound, they would enter the word to guess it?

As an example in level 1, player will be given the sound of cat,dog,parrot and hamster, and have to guess the common between the four sounds. The player after hearing the sounds will be notified that the word consist of 3 letters and they have to guess what is it. If let say the player inserts the letter "E" the "E" will be inserted in the missing word and the player needs to guess the remaining words. The correct word for this will be "PET". How do I code this in Phaser?

(Btw The game has no graphics or animations because it is for blind users).

I get error message **"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {** " at the line "**if (game.input.keyboard.isDown(Phaser.Keyboard.P) {** "

The input I'm still trying to play after hearing the four sounds are not working. I have no idea where I have gone wrong.

My code:

```
  var game = new Phaser.Game(400,490, Phaser.AUTO, 'gameDiv');
  var key1;
  var key2;
  var key3;
  var key4;
  var speech;
  var level1;
  var PCorrect;
  var ECorrect;
  var TCorrect;
  var TryAgain;
  var mainState = {


preload: function() {
    game.stage.backgroundColor ='#71c5cf'
    game.load.audio('the_intro', 'assets/speech_intro.wav');
    game.load.audio('start', 'assets/cat_meow.wav');
    game.load.audio('second', 'assets/dog_bark.wav');
    game.load.audio('third', 'assets/mouse_squeak.wav');
    game.load.audio('fourth', 'assets/parrot.wav');
    game.load.audio('default' , 'assets/wrong_key.wav');
    game.load.audio('levelPet' , 'assets/GuessPet.wav');
    game.load.audio('P', 'assets/PforPet.wav');
    game.load.audio('T', 'assets/TforPet.wav');
    game.load.audio('E', 'assets/EforPet.wav');
    game.load.audio('Try','assets/WrongAnswer.wav');

},


create: function() {

     //introduction narration
     speech = game.add.audio('the_intro');

     speech.play();

    //Sound added 1st
    this.meowSound = game.add.audio('start');
    this.barkSound = game.add.audio('second');
    this.softSound = game.add.audio('third');
    this.talkingSound = game.add.audio('fourth');
    this.noSound = game.add.audio('default');

    //Call the sound when the key is pressed
    var self = this;
    game.input.keyboard.onDownCallback = function(e) {
        var keycode = e.keycode || e.which;

        switch(keycode) {

            case Phaser.Keyboard.ONE:
                 self.addCat();
               break;

            case Phaser.Keyboard.TWO:
               self.addDog();
               break;

            case Phaser.Keyboard.THREE:
                self.addMouse();
                break;

            case Phaser.Keyboard.FOUR:
                 self.addParrot();

                  level1 = game.add.audio('levelPet');
                  level1.play();
                 break;

            default:
                 self.addOthers();
                 break;
               break;



        }


    }


  },

update: function(){

    this.PLevel1 = game.add.audio('P');
    this.ELevel1 = game.add.audio('E');
    this.TLevel1 = game.add.audio('T');
    this.WrongAns = game.add.audion('Try');

    var self = this;

    if (acceptInput) {
    if (game.input.keyboard.isDown(Phaser.Keyboard.P) {

        self.addP();

    } else if (game.input.keyboard.isDown(Phaser.Keyboard.E)) {

        self.addE();

    } else if (game.input.keyboard.isDown(Phaser.Keyboard.T)) {
        self.addT();
    }

     else 
     {
        self.addWrong();
     }





  }

  }


addCat: function() {

    this.meowSound.play();
},

addDog: function() {
    this.barkSound.play();
},

addMouse: function() {
    this.softSound.play();
},

addParrot: function() {
    this.talkingSound.play();
},

addOthers: function() {
    this.noSound.play();
},

addP: function() {
    this.PLevel1.play();
}

addE: function() {
    this.ELevel1.play();

 }

addT: function() {
    this.TLevel1.play();
}

addWrong: function() {
    this.WrongAns.play();
}
};



game.state.add('main', mainState);
game.state.start('main');
```

Comment: You're missing a `)`

Comment: Thank you so much. But still the input is not working. Am I missing any references to call the update function?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is junk.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you don't listen for specific keys, but all of them. You can do that with the `Keyboard.addCallbacks` method. The signature is this:

`/**
* Add callbacks to the Keyboard handler so that each time a key is pressed down or released the callbacks are activated.
*
* @method Phaser.Keyboard#addCallbacks
* @param {Object} context - The context under which the callbacks are run.
* @param {function} [onDown=null] - This callback is invoked every time a key is pressed down.
* @param {function} [onUp=null] - This callback is invoked every time a key is released.
* @param {function} [onPress=null] - This callback is invoked every time the onkeypress event is raised.
*/
addCallbacks: function (context, onDown, onUp, onPress) {`

You only need to know about the onPress event, so you could do:

`game.input.keyboard.addCallbacks(this, null, null, keyPress);`

Where `keyPress` is the name of the function that is called when a key is pressed. This function will be sent the character that was pressed as a string. So in this function if you were looking for the word PET from the player, you could check to see if the key pressed was P, E or T and highlight it accordingly. Here's a working example I put together for you: http://examples.phaser.io/debug.php?f=input/word+input.js

Comment: Thank you so much. That means if i use the addCallbacks method it listens to all of the key and will highlight the necessary key that the user needs? And also does this means I don't need the update function?

Comment: Correct. It listens for ALL keys - so sometimes you may need to handle special ones like backspace, delete or enter, to make sure your game doesn't act strangely. But that's down to your game, not a Phaser thing.